# Battery drain while transmitting Eddystone beacons

Tags: beacon, eddystone

I am trying to use an Android device to transmit Eddystone beacons. I would like to know the approximate battery drain the device consumes to transmit beacons in the background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news!  **The battery drain of transmitting as a beacon from a mobile phone is negligible**.   I did some tests on both Android and iOS to measure this drain, and found to my surprise that I couldn't even come up with a number.  The drain was so small it was within the margin of error of the test setup.

The Android version of these tests happened to use the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) to transmit an AltBeacon frame, but I have seen similar results using the same library to transmit an Eddystone frame.  And since the library simply wraps lower-level Android APIs, these numbers are applicable regardless of what API you are using to set up the transmission.

See [this blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/12/09/battery-friendly-beacon-transmission.html) for details.